# Computer has been automatically booting into GNU GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mac

I have a MacBook pro and I tried to install Ubuntu on a USB through this computer. It was successful, since I now have Ubuntu on a USB. Whenever I do not have the USB plugged into the computer, I boot into a screen titled `GNU GRUB` which, for the few of you that maybe not know, is like a command line interface in which you can do... (I'm still trying to figure that out).

This is very bad since I wanted to make a portable workspace that I could use whenever I want to. But I need to delete the GNU GRUB that the computer is automatically trying to boot into.

I tried to delete a partition named GNU GRUB, but nothing happened. I also tried to change the `Boot Drive` in settings for my Mac but it is already booting into `Macintosh HD` with the `MacOS` operating system. I really need help, since this is very annoying and my family (with whom I sometimes share this computer) does not like to have to hold alt every single time they try to do something.

Please help

P.D. when on the mac startup manager, the thing that I am booting into is called `EFI BOOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit the default that grub will boot, boot your USB Ubuntu disk and edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and set the `GRUB_DEFAULT=` to the (0-based!) number of the entry you use when you see the grub menu to get to MacOS (after holding Alt). (So: first entry: 0, third entry: 2, etc). Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

To 'set' the default option you'll boot by default (being MacOS for your family members).

Also, you could change `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=` to `false` - this will always show the menu (without pressing Alt).

A side note: On dual boot systems, I set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and add a line `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`. This will make grub remember what was started last.

Don't forget `sudo update-grub` after *every* update of `/etc/default/grub`.